# Three.js: Objects intersected and shader material

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have a scene with objects intersected using Lambert material, like in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arnaldof/ps82nsf8/1/).

Now I need/want to switch the material of that plane to a Shader material and the plane turns into a background thing, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Arnaldof/h7s6mv15/1/).

The question is, can I use different materials in objects and still preserve the intersection effect? Is this a Three.js limitation or this is how shaders works? Or am I missing a parameter in the renderer/material?

At the moment is not an option no switch all my work to shader materials in order to take advantage of shaders.

This is how I set up the material:

```
var material1 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { 
    uniforms: {
        color: { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0x22A8E7 ) }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent, 
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent, 
    opacity: 0.5, 
    transparent: true, 
} );
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to make any progress with this?

Comment: @Shomz, not yet. I've made the question tired of looking the web and no luck. Switch all my scene to shader material is not that hard as I thought using scene.overrideMaterial = <generic_shader>, but I will lost all my textures, lights and shadows since I'm new to shaders and I can't code those things.

Comment: I thought so, I upvoted the question when you posted it, and was later curious about the progress. Let's hope some shader expert will know the answer.

Comment: @Shomz, in case you are still curious about this, I've found something. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I'm glad you found a solution, but I don't like the solution itself, it looks like a bug indeed. Do you think it might be worth reaching out to three.js team? (I was actually hoping one of them would answer your question here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ShaderMaterial you control the shader glsl; so in order for logarithmicDepthBuffer to work you need to add four sets of code to your shaders.

The code is in:

Vertex shader declares

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/logdepthbuf_pars_vertex.glsl

```
#ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF

    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT

        varying float vFragDepth;

    #endif

    uniform float logDepthBufFC;

#endif
```

Vertex shader body

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/logdepthbuf_vertex.glsl

```
#ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF

    gl_Position.z = log2(max( EPSILON, gl_Position.w + 1.0 )) * logDepthBufFC;

    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT

        vFragDepth = 1.0 + gl_Position.w;

    #else

        gl_Position.z = (gl_Position.z - 1.0) * gl_Position.w;

    #endif

#endif
```

Fragment shader declares

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/logdepthbuf_pars_fragment.glsl

```
#ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF

    uniform float logDepthBufFC;

    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT

        #extension GL_EXT_frag_depth : enable
        varying float vFragDepth;

    #endif

#endif
```

Fragment shader body

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/logdepthbuf_fragment.glsl

```
#if defined(USE_LOGDEPTHBUF) && defined(USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT)

    gl_FragDepthEXT = log2(vFragDepth) * logDepthBufFC * 0.5;

#endif
```

If you are building the shaders in js, rather than pulling directly from the HTML then you can include these with ShaderChunks e.g. `THREE.ShaderChunk[ "logdepthbuf_pars_vertex" ]`

See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js for examples of this.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just to note, only adding the snippets in the vertex shader were enough for me. I've included both and works too, maybe the VS is just fine to my task.

Comment: Great advice! Thank you! Two more tips: 
1. Shader chunks are just text snippets saved in THREE.ShaderChunk object. Evaluation of `THREE.ShaderChunk.logdepthbuf_fragment` will output a string which you can concat with your main shader code.
 2. `THREE.ShaderChunk.logdepthbuf_pars_vertex` refers to constant `EPSILON` which wasn't found in my case. I had to pass js constant Number.EPSILON into the shader as a uniform for this snippet to work.

Other than that, worked as a charm.

Comment: This is incredible. Thank you for actually pasting the code, some of these links have since died and this quickly got me on the right track after struggling for days. It's a bit dated and doesn't work well with Three 135 (nonetheless couldn't have done it without you :)), so for future visitors I've created a fiddle based on this that runs v135 and uses multi-scene rendering combined with the [vanruesc/postprocessing](https://github.com/vanruesc/postprocessing) lib, all with a log z buff and a skybox 1e6 meters wide: https://jsfiddle.net/devilishfiddler/r5wkcbxf/

Answer (score 2):

Ok, looking for another subject, I've found this example http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Glow.html.

The "problem" in my tests was the **logarithmic depth buffer** in this line:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({logarithmicDepthBuffer: true});
```

Without that option, worked as expected.

Now, I don't know if that is a bug in THREE or in order to use logarithmic depth buffer I must write the shader in another way, or it just the way it is.

Comment: `logarithmicDepthBuffer` is used to render *massive* scenes more easily (for example, you can render the galaxy to scale in units of meters using `logarithmicDepthBuffer`). It does this at the expense of messing with depth testing, which is likely why you had issues. Removing it causes massive glitching in scenes larger than a few kilometers wide, but adding it makes shaders more complicated to manage.