# Using WebGLRenderer with logarithmicDepthBufferset option set to true together with ShaderMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I use the following `ShaderMaterial` for my objects in scene. The code below is working. However, if I set the WebGLRenderer option `logarithmicDepthBuffer` to `true`, the Material defined below is not displayed correctly.

```
new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      color1: {
        value: new THREE.Color('#3a0000')
      },
      color2: {
        value: new THREE.Color('#ffa9b0')
      }
    },
    vertexShader: `
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    void main(void){
      vNormal      = normalMatrix * normalize(normal);
      gl_Position  = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
    }`,

    fragmentShader: `
    uniform vec3 color1;
    uniform vec3 color2;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    void main(void){
      vec3 view_nv  = normalize(vNormal);
      vec3 nv_color = view_nv * 0.5 + 0.5;
      vec3 c = mix(color1, color2, nv_color.r);
      gl_FragColor  = vec4(c, 1.0);
    }`,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  });
```

**After looking for a solution to this problem, I found the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217468/three-js-objects-intersected-and-shader-material). Summarizing, the solution is to add 4 pieces of code to `vertexShader` and `fragmentShader`.**

***Where exactly do I have to integrate the provided code snippets, i.e. Vertex shader body and Fragment shader body?***

I tried various "positions" but I always got WebGL errors.

```
THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error: 0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog Must have a compiled vertex shader attached. ERROR: 0:63: 'EPSILON' : undeclared identifier
```

---

**UPDATE** added playground: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gQoaye

If you add the option of `logarithmicDepthBuffer` to the constructor, you will see that the `ShaderMaterial` won't work anymore.

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(logarithmicDepthBuffer:true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where exactly do I have to integrate the provided code snippets, i.e. Vertex shader body and Fragment shader body?

In the vertex shader you have to define `EPSILON`.
After adding the code snipptes [logdepthbuf_pars_vertex.glsl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/logdepthbuf_vertex.glsl) and [logdepthbuf_vertex.glsl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/logdepthbuf_vertex.glsl), the final vertex shader is:

```
#ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
#define EPSILON 1e-6
#ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
varying float vFragDepth;
#endif
uniform float logDepthBufFC;
#endif

varying vec3 vNormal;

void main(void){
    vNormal      = normalMatrix * normalize(normal);
    gl_Position  = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);

#ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
    gl_Position.z = log2(max( EPSILON, gl_Position.w + 1.0 )) * logDepthBufFC;
#ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
    vFragDepth = 1.0 + gl_Position.w;
#else
    gl_Position.z = (gl_Position.z - 1.0) * gl_Position.w;
#endif
#endif
}
```

After adding the code snippets, the final fragment shader is:

```
#ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
uniform float logDepthBufFC;
#ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
#extension GL_EXT_frag_depth : enable
varying float vFragDepth;
#endif
#endif

uniform vec3 color1;
uniform vec3 color2;
varying vec3 vNormal;
void main(void){
    vec3 view_nv  = normalize(vNormal);
    vec3 nv_color = view_nv * 0.5 + 0.5;
    vec3 c = mix(color1, color2, nv_color.r);
    gl_FragColor  = vec4(c, 1.0);

#if defined(USE_LOGDEPTHBUF) && defined(USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT)
    gl_FragDepthEXT = log2(vFragDepth) * logDepthBufFC * 0.5;
#endif
}
```

See the example:

```js
(function onLoad() {
  var container, camera, scene, renderer, orbitControls;
  
  function createModel() {

    var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      color1: {
        value: new THREE.Color('#3a0000')
      },
      color2: {
        value: new THREE.Color('#ffa9b0')
      }
    },
    vertexShader: `
    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
    #define EPSILON 1e-6
    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
    varying float vFragDepth;
    #endif
    uniform float logDepthBufFC;
    #endif

    varying vec3 vNormal;
    
    void main(void){
        vNormal      = normalMatrix * normalize(normal);
        gl_Position  = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);

    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
        gl_Position.z = log2(max( EPSILON, gl_Position.w + 1.0 )) * logDepthBufFC;
    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
        vFragDepth = 1.0 + gl_Position.w;
    #else
        gl_Position.z = (gl_Position.z - 1.0) * gl_Position.w;
    #endif
    #endif
    }`,

    fragmentShader: `
    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF
    #ifdef USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT
    #extension GL_EXT_frag_depth : enable
    varying float vFragDepth;
    #endif
    uniform float logDepthBufFC;
    #endif

    uniform vec3 color1;
    uniform vec3 color2;
    varying vec3 vNormal;
    void main(void){
        vec3 view_nv  = normalize(vNormal);
        vec3 nv_color = view_nv * 0.5 + 0.5;
        vec3 c = mix(color1, color2, nv_color.r);
        gl_FragColor  = vec4(c, 1.0);
        
    #if defined(USE_LOGDEPTHBUF) && defined(USE_LOGDEPTHBUF_EXT)
        gl_FragDepthEXT = log2(vFragDepth) * logDepthBufFC * 0.5;
    #endif
    }`,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  });

    //var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'#b090b0'});
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  function init() {
    container = document.getElementById('container');
    
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true,
      logarithmicDepthBuffer: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, -2);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
    scene.add(camera);
    window.onresize = resize;

    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container);
    
    var helper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 100);
    helper.material.opacity = 0.25;
    helper.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(helper);

    var axis = new THREE.AxesHelper(1000);
    scene.add(axis);

    createModel();
  }

  function resize() {  
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    orbitControls.update();
    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  
  init();
  animate();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have tried inserting that code in your two shaders? To my understanding, that should be correct.

The error appears to be complaining about the shader not compiling, due to a reference to `EPSILON` in the vertex shader body, although `EPSILON` was never declared.

Try defining `EPSILON`, e.g. using a macro in the shader itself:

```
#define EPSILON 1e-6
```

or pass it to the shader as a uniform. (Notice that this is just an example value; you may want to research what a suitable value for `EPSILON` might be in your particular case.)

Comment: Unfortunately this will lead to a new error: `THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error: 0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog Must have a compiled vertex shader attached. ERROR: 0:56: 'endifvarying' : invalid directive name
ERROR: 0:57: 'gl_Position' : syntax error`